# Python print Filename and Extention from directory and sub directories

Tags: python, file, printing, directory, filenames

Hello I am trying to write a python script that can look through a directory and sub directories and pull out the file names and extensions and lists them in a file. thank you for your time.
Example Outputneeded:

```
Artist
 Album name
  song.mp3
  song.wav
  song.aiff
```

the files are stored as Artist, Albums{could be many here}, songs{per album}

I am currently trying to start this with:

```
import os

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):

    for subdirname in dirnames:
        print os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)


    for filename in filenames:
        print os.path.join(dirname, filename)
```

Comment: just open a file first  and write as you go

Answer (score 0):

You can track how far you've gone down the tree by counting path separators in the base directory.

```
import os

def scan_this(path):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    sep_count = path.count(os.path.sep) + 1

    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        nest_count = root.count(os.path.sep) - sep_count
        if nest_count <= 1:
            print '%s%s' % ('  ' * nest_count, os.path.basename(root))
            if nest_count == 1:
                for f in filenames:
                    print '%s%s' % ('  ' * (nest_count + 1), f)

scan_this('.')
```